# Where is the error "The view function did not return a valid response. " in my flask app?

Tags: python, mysql, csv, flask

The Error

```
(app) E:\skripsi_app>python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2019 22:17:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2019 22:17:16] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2019-03-03 22:17:17,884] ERROR in app: Exception on /dataset [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\skripsi_app\app\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "E:\skripsi_app\app\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "E:\skripsi_app\app\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1831, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
File "E:\skripsi_app\app\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1957, in make_response
    'The view function did not return a valid response. The'
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2019 22:17:17] "GET /dataset HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

dataset function in app.py

```
@app.route('/dataset',methods=['GET','POST'])
def dataset():
if request.method == 'POST':

    file = request.files['file']

    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return redirect(request.url)

    if file.filename == '':
        return redirect(request.url)

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return render_template('dataset.html')
```

in html

```
<strong>Upload Data</strong>
      <br>
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <button type="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
      </form>
```

At first, I've added function `dataset` on `app.py` and ran it. This app is okay, it works for me for payload csv, but when I click another link like `chart.html` for example and back to page `dataset.html`, the error happens.
Please help me to fix this

Comment: When none of your `if` statements are fulfilled, `dataset` function returns `None` which is not a valid response. Just add default behaviour at the end of `dataset` function. Perhaps it should be `return render_template('dataset.html')` or `return render_template('error_page.html')` if you treat that as an error/unwanted behaviour.

Comment: whuaaa i add "return render_template('dataset.html')" at the end. it works. thank you @needtobe
and, one more thing, do you know how to import csv or excel into database mysql with flask?
i already search, in the code in function dataset, the function just upload to a folder not into database?

Comment: I would highly recommend using `flask-sqlalchemy`.

Comment: or can you import a csv file from a webpage using flask, in webpage you just browse your file and click import and show the content of file in a table. just like that not import to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments section:

When none of your if statements are fulfilled, dataset function returns None which is not a valid response. Just add default behaviour at the end of dataset function. Perhaps it should be `return render_template('dataset.html')` or `return render_template('error_page.html')` if you treat that as an error/unwanted behaviour.